# synchronous actions in node js

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I want to run these three actions in an ordered manner:

1. Opening the serial port
2. Listening to any changes
3. Sending commands via serial port

The problem is because of the asynchronicity of node js, sometimes data is sent before the port starts listening. Hence, this data is lost. Here is my sample code. How can I solve this problem?

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM27", {
  baudrate: 57600
}, false); // this is the openImmediately flag [default is true]

//***1***open the serialport
serialPort.open(function (error) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log('failed to open: '+error);
  }
  else {
    console.log('open');
  }

  //***2***port is now listening
  serialPort.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('data received: ' + data)
  })

  //***3***send command using serialport
  serialPort.write("AJ+APN?\n", function(err, results) {
    console.log('err ' + err);
    console.log('results ' + results)
  })
});
```

Comment: It looks like you are dutifully waiting for the port to be open, There is a note that Node versions above 0.11.10 are not supported, what version of node are you running?

Comment: The version of node js is 0.12.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a promise for each of the tasks that should execute in series. Then it should be simple chaining of the promises in the required order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the serialport module you're using, but if it's "standard" in the way it behaves then:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM27", { baudrate: 57600 }, false);

//***1*** listen for events on port
serialPort.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('data received: ' + data);

//***2*** open the serialport
serialPort.open(function (error) {
  if ( error ) {
    console.log('failed to open: '+error);
  } else {
    console.log('open');

    //***3*** send command using serialport -> after port opened
    serialPort.write("AJ+APN?\n", function(err, results) {
      console.log('err ' + err);
      console.log('results ' + results)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) the documentation says not to install the listeners before opening (https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#open-event)

2) this wouldn't write OPs initial data until there was data received

3) this would write OPs initial data EVERY time there was data received

Comment: @trex - 1) as I wrote in the answer, I'm not familiar with this module, but since you provided the link (great that you did BTW), then "*installing 'data' listeners and writing before the open event might result in... nothing at all*" (looks very safe to me). 2, 3) I see I didn't understand the intentions in the question. fixing...

Comment: 1) yes, you were clear, just helping out 2) OP wanted the port to be listening, but we don't have any reason to believe it would have transmitted any data 3) :)